# How to open file in console via GUI?

Tags: terminal, wine

For instance, if I have `.exe` file and I double click on it, *something* should open terminal with command `wine file.exe`.

Maybe there is some kind of app that can do this?

open file -> 
associate extension with some program -> 
launch command inside the terminal

Comment: .exe extension says the file is a Windows program.  Your on a mac.  You may be able to get the file to run with Wine or you install windows in bootcamp or in some virtual machine.

Comment: that's why I asked how to open file with wine just by clicking on it

Comment: This sounds like a great reason to make a small stub app that claims that file type and then grabs the input and launches. I can see all of the pieces are likely doable, but it will need some cleverness and testing to get the work done.